# IntRange with long parameters

Tags: android, androidx

I was looking into `IntRange` implementation at Android support library, and I noticed both `from` and `to` parameters are of type long, and by default they use long max and min values.
Here is the official documentation for a reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntRange.html#from()

My question is, why is it a `long` if it is defining an `int` range, why could it be required or useful at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Denotes that the annotated element should be an int or long in the given range

In the documentation it is noted that the annotated element should be an int or long so I guess it is to avoid creating a separate class for `LongRange`.

And as the long values can be way more than int values therefore the `IntRange.from()` and `IntRange.to()` should be of type `Long`